# How to Autowire SessionFactory from AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I am working on a annotation based spring configuration, and I want to use Hibernate as well.  I have an AnnotationSessionFactoryBean:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    annotationSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    annotationSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    annotationSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.mobiusinversion.web");
    return annotationSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

But now in my code how do I Autowire in the SessionFactory as in:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}
```

Comment: Should this just work?  I didn't think that Spring would understand how to inject a SessionFactory with a AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` is both an `InitializingBean` and a `FactoryBean`. These are special interfaces which Spring processes as part of the bean lifecycle. `InitializingBean` will provide `afterProperties` set to initialize the bean and `FactoryBean` will provide `getObject` for retrieving the bean. That bean is then added to the context.

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` produces a `SessionFactory` bean, so, yes, all you then have to do is autowire it

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

This is all explained in the documentation:

- [`InitializingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean)
- [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

You should also go through the javadoc.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  And thank you very much for the clear and detailed explanation of how it works, Im still learning about Spring and that is very helpful.